# jQuery selector performace: find() + not() + :has combination

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I need to filter huge html files (~100MB) and remove some parts from it. Divs are structured in tree, algorithm removes leaf nodes and iterates while there is nothing to remove. Simplified code:

```
var $d = $(htmlString);
var leafs = $d.find('.section[data-security]').not(':has(.section[data-security])');
while(leafs.length) {    
    leafs.each(/* 
       - compare attribute data-security with user based values
       - call leaf.remove() 
       - break iteration when nothing was removed */)
    leafs = $d.find('.section[data-security]').not(':has(.section[data-security])');
}
$('#document').append($d);
```

Q: How to rewrite selector `$d.find('.section[data-security]').not(':has(.section[data-security])')` to gain more performace ?

Selector runs in first iteration about 5sec (60k leafs selected), second round of iteration takes 1sec on select (1500 leafs), others <100ms.

NOT all DIV.section has the data-security attribute:

```
<div class="section" data-security="{some json 1}">
    <div class="section" >
        <div class="section"  data-security="{some json data 1.1}" > leaf </div>     
        <div class="section"  data-security="{some json data 1.2}">  -- leaf
            <div class="section" > </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section"  data-security="{some json data 1.3}">    
            <div class="section"  data-security="{some json data 1.3.1}"> leaf </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. You can try to write the same (I mean elements' select) without jQuery - if you will do this correctly, it should work faster. 2. You can use simple `for` instead of `.each()` - it works faster. 3. Check what you do inside `.each()` and `while`. I suspect that `leafs = ...` inside `while` is not the best idea at all - you have already selected elements before `while` - why not to modify list of selected ones instead of re-selecting them?

Comment: Thanx for your answer, 1. native `querySelectorAll()` does not have the `:has` selector - it's jQuery specific. 2. will try 3. because the new leafs list will contain new elements  - e.g. parent of a removed leaf, becomes leaf... - now trying: select all nodes with `[data-security]` attribute, mark them with section-secured class, then leaf selector in iterations does `leafs = nodes.not(':has(.secured-section)')`

Comment: 1. This is what I'm talking about: you can write your own implementation of `:has()` for your specific situation. For example, you can take it from jQuery source code. Even without modifications it should work faster without `$()`. Maybe there are some cross-browser hacks in this code piece - you can delete them to speed up process. 3. It **might** be, that removing one object (leaf) and adding its parent (if it becomes leaf) to list (jQuery's object) is faster than reselecting whole tree, but it should be tested.